# Custom-formatted cells not working properly in Excel graphs

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula, formatting, excel-2016

I have a table with 2 names, coexisting date and I had to extract the year and month from the date cell. I did it with custom format (`mm` and `yyyy`). This is how I got month from date cell:
[image]

I want to make a graph of people born each month. But when I pick a name and month column I get very strange results.

First, I cannot get my graph to display text on x-axis and my y-axis has different values than stored in custom-formatted cells.

Data:

```
name   date         month      year
a      6.11.1940     11        1940
b      11.02.1920    02        1920
```

My output graph looks like this

[image]

Then, I would like labels `a` and `b` on the x-axis. We see that the first point is 11 and the second is 2. I don't even know where do labels on y axis come from.

Comment: You have a picture of example in the text now.

Comment: Okay, and can you show an example of your desired graph?

Comment: I want to have names on x-axis and months on y-axis Column "name" for x series and column "month" for y series.

Comment: I can post the answer which does exacly this (months on y-axis), but just know that it will be the simpliest interpretation if you do not specify :)

Comment: haha I don't understand :) i want to know why number 11 on column "month" is not presented on the graph as 11 and same for number 02. and why does graph post weird numbers on y axis like 01, 0.6 12 06 11 05 11 04 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use custom format in the `month` column. If the date `6.11.1940` is in the cell `B2` then in the cell `C2` write this: `=MONTH(B2)`. And equivalent below. Make sure that the column `C` has the data type of `General`.

Then you must get this graph (names on x, months on y, as required):

[image: the graph]

In your case, you received strange values, because on Y axis you did not only have months. You had full dates, but you only saw the months out of the full date range.

Comment: No, sorry already tried with the =month(b2), I get 01, not 11 :) Maybe cause my date number is set to "Date" cell function

Comment: If you do not get 11, then Excel does not understand that the month is 11 in B2. I'm not sure why it thinks, it's 1

Comment: neither do I. Hope someone else has some better idea than us two :)

Comment: If I switch from date cell type to general I get 15683

Comment: This number is the date 1942-12-08, is it correct?

Comment: If 1940-11-06 has the same DATE cell type, then MONTH() should nicely show 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225404/discussion-between-noob-programmer-and-zygd).